# Stata output files in surveys (proportions)

Tags: stata

I need to modify the code below which I'm using on some CPS data to capture insurance coverage.  I need to output a file with the percent covered by Census region (there are four).  It should look something like this:

```
region n     percent
1      xxx   xx
2      xxx   xx
3      xxx   xx
4      xxx   xx
```

I could live with two rows defining the percentages covered and not covered in each region if necessary, but I really only need the percentage covered.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
svyset [iw=hinswt], sdrweight(repwt1-repwt160) vce(sdr)

tempname memhold
postfile `memhold' region_rec n prop using Insurance, replace
levelsof region_rec, local(lf)

foreach x of local lf{
svy, subpop(if region_rec==`x' & age>=3  & age<=17): proportion hcovany
scalar forx = `x'
scalar prop = _b[hcovany]

matrix  b =  e(_N_subp)
matrix c = e(_N)
scalar n = el(c,1,1)
post `memhold' (forx) (n) (prop) 
}

postclose `memhold'
use Insurance, clear
list
```

This is what it produces:

```
Survey: Proportion estimation    Number of obs    =     210648
                                 Population size  =  291166198
                                 Subpop. no. obs  =      10829
                                 Subpop. size     = 10965424.5
                                 Replications     =        160

  _prop_1: hcovany = Not covered

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |                 SDR
             | Proportion   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
hcovany      |
     _prop_1 |   .0693129   .0046163      .0602651    .0783607
     Covered |   .9306871   .0046163      .9216393    .9397349
--------------------------------------------------------------
[hcovany] not found
r(111);
```

I can't figure out how to get around the error message at the bottom and get it to save the results.  I think a SE and CV would be a desirable feature as well, but I'm not sure how to handle that within the matrix framework.

EDIT: Additional output

```
     +----------------------------------+
     | region~c       n       prop   se |
     |----------------------------------|
     |        1    9640   .9360977    2 |
     |        2   12515   .9352329    2 |
     |        3   14445   .8769684    2 |
     |        4   13241   .8846368    2 |
     +----------------------------------+
```

Comment: hi, i know this isn't your main question, but you are calculating the standard error incorrectly.  i assume you are using [this document](http://www.isr.umich.edu/src/smp/asda/Additional%20Stata%20Examples%20svy%20sdr.pdf) as your guide?  that is not a fay's adjustment with rho=0.5 [as recommended by the census bureau](http://www.census.gov/prod/2006pubs/tp-66.pdf#page=108).  [if there were ever a time to learn r](http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/current%20population%20survey%20%28cps%29), it's right now   ;)

Comment: @AnthonyDamico Actually following this guidance: [link]https://cps.ipums.org/cps/repwt.shtml#q60.  If you're correct, no need to use R.  Simply modify svyset to say: svyset [iw=wtsupp], brrweight(repwtp1-repwtp160) fay(.05) vce(brr).  I've asked IPUMS for clarification.

Comment: it's `fay(0.5)` and not `fay(.05)`

Comment: I looked at the documentation you referenced and it says, "The current approach to estimating the 1990 and 2000 design variances is called successive difference replication."  Thus the sdr option on the svyset.  IPUMS told me the .5 multiplier is handled internally by Stata 12.  A svyset [iw=hinswt], sdrweight(repwtp1-repwtp160) vce(sdr) or a svyset [iw=wtsupp], brrweight(repwtp1-repwtp160) fay(.5) vce(brr) yields the same standard errors.  So, no problems with the IPUMS guidance.

Comment: I find this last edit in form of a table confusing for future visitors. You post a question asking
for help to solve some problem and immediatley after display a table that implies
you do not have such problem. I assume you show this table so we can see that
you have (new) problems saving the standard errors as you mention in a comment to an
answer. I think this problem is best left alone in the comments and that this 
table is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `_b[hcovany]` for `_b[some-value-label]`. To be clear, the following non-sensical example is similar to your code, but instead of using `_b[sex]`, where `sex` is a variable, it uses `_b[Male]`, where `Male` is a value label for `sex`. Subpopulation sizes and standard errors
are also saved.

```
clear all
set more off

webuse nhanes2f
svyset [pweight=finalwgt]

tempname memhold
tempfile results
postfile `memhold' region nsubpop maleprop stderr using `results', replace

levelsof region, local(lf)

foreach x of local lf{
    svy, subpop(if region == `x' & inrange(age, 20, 40)): proportion sex
    post `memhold' (`x') (e(N_subpop)) (_b[Male]) (_se[Male])
}

postclose `memhold'

use `results', clear
list
```

If we were to use `_b[sex]` instead of `_b[Male]`, we would get the same `r(111)` error as in your original post.

For this example, lets see what the matrix `e(b)`, containing the estimated proportions, looks like:

```
. matrix list e(b)

e(b)[1,2]
          sex:       sex:
         Male     Female
y1  .48821487  .51178513
```

Therefore, if we wanted to extract the proportions for females instead
of males, we could use `_b[Female]`.

Yet another option is to save the estimation result in a matrix and use numerical subscripts:

```
<snip>
matrix b = e(b)
post `memhold' (`x') (b[1,2]) 
<snip>
```

There are other slight changes like the use of `inrange` and direct use of returned estimation results with `post`.

Also, you may want to take a look at `help _variables` and its link:

> [U] 13.5 Accessing coefficients and standard errors.

Comment: This works if I say scalar prop1 = _b[Covered].  However, if I add scalar prop2 = _b[Not covered] to cover the other category, I get an error: [Notcovered] not found. The matrix e(label1) : "'"Not covered"' Covered", so I'm not sure where this _prop_1 comes from and how to get the proper label to display in the output, or how to retain the values in the not covered category.  Guidance appreciated.

Comment: It seems that in this case, Stata doesn't like the space in your value label `Not covered`. In fact, I believe it tells you so when it outputs `_prop_1: hcovany = Not covered`. One option is to use `_prop_1` as the relevant value label: `_b[_prop_1]`. Another is to change your value label replacing the blank with underscore: `label define hcoveny what-ever-value "Not_covered", modify`, and run `proportion` afterwards. Read `help label` for details. A third way is to use numerical subscripts as already covered in the answer.

Comment: Ok, I've tried a couple of ways to save the SE.  First, I set up matrix v = e(V).  Then, following an example, I tried scalar sd = sqrt(el(b,1,1), but it returned 2.  Next, I tried scalar se = sqrt(v[1,1]), but received the same result.  I'm specifying postfile `memhold' region_rec n prop se using InsuranceStat2005, replace and post `memhold' (forx) (n) (prop) (se), so I think I should be getting what's being computed, but it's not working.

Comment: Standard errors can be retrieved directly from `_se`. I've edited the code in the answer to save both subpopulation sizes and standard errors.